# Can use Meshlab dlls (filter_unsharp) in a c# application

Tags: c#, meshlab

I try to apply a laplacien smoothing filter to my stl file.

In Meshlab, under the menu Filter/Smoothing there is Laplacien smoothing options which works perfectly.

It comes from filter_unsharp dll. I searched but couldn't find any source to use in C# or any code example .

Can it be possible to use the apply filter fonction of the dll in a c# application ?

I tried to add as reference but it says that is impossible.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the answer.
In the installation folder of Meshlab, there is meshlabserver.exe which we can use via command line.

For example, to apply a laplacian smoothing, the command line code is

```
 MeshlabInstallationFolderPath\meshlabserver -i C:\Users\my_user\Source\left.stl -o C:\Users\my_user\smoothed.stl -s LaplacianFilter.mlx
```

And the content of the LaplacianFilter.mlx file :

```
<FilterScript>
  <filter name="Laplacian Smooth">
   <Param name="stepSmoothNum" tooltip="" description="" isxmlparam="0" value="3" type="RichInt"/>
   <Param name="selection" tooltip="" description="" isxmlparam="0" value="false" type="RichBool"/>
   <Param name="boundarySmooth" tooltip="" description="" isxmlparam="0" value="true" type="RichBool"/>
   <Param name="cotangentWeight" tooltip="" description="" isxmlparam="0" value="true" type="RichBool"/>
  </filter>
</FilterScript>
```

It opens the source file, applies the laplacian filter and saves the smoothed file.

Comment: it will be better if Meshlab can export APIs to be invoked from c# or c++